# Give Direction in iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary

In my application, I have phone number and address as attached in the figure, whenever user clicks on phone number which is blue text color, it directly calls the company. I would like to add similar feature for the address. Whenever user clicks on the address, it should take user to the map with direction.

Is there way to make it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to make this happen. You can load that address directly into the Maps app (per nsdebug's answer), or you can use Core Location / Mapping to get an X/Y coordinate for that address. That is called geocoding:

https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=iOS+Geocoding&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8